# How do I include PHP and pass in a query so that it renders without the query string in the URL

Tags: php

I'm returning some query results via API call and need to include the results based on a query string. Here is the code:

**loadTest.php:**

```
function doTest($test)
{
    global $debugInfo;
    try {
        $session = new SkiddleSDK\SkiddleSession(['api_key'=>'APIKEYHERE','dev_mode'=>true]);
    } catch (SkiddleSDK\SkiddleException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    $events = new SkiddleSDK\Events;
    try {
        $events->setSession($session);
    } catch (SkiddleSDK\SkiddleException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    $connect_block = <<<BLOCK
    
\$session = new SkiddleSDK\SkiddleSession(['api_key'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']);

\$events = new SkiddleSDK\Events;
\$events->setSession(\$session);


BLOCK;

    switch ($test) {
        case 4:
            //test 4 - keyword
            try {
                $events->addCond('p','123456');
                $events->addCond('keyword','Keyword');
                $results = $events->getListings();
                $debugInfo = $events->getDebugInfo();
                $debugInfo .= highlight_string('<?php '.$connect_block.'$events->addCond(\'keyword\',\'Teletech\');
$results = $events->getListings(); ?>',true);
            } catch (SkiddleSDK\SkiddleException $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
            return $results;
            break;
        default:
            //everything
            try {
                $results = $events->getListings();
                $debugInfo = $events->getDebugInfo();
                $debugInfo .= highlight_string('<?php '.$connect_block.'$results = $events->getListings(); ?>',true);
            } catch (SkiddleSDK\SkiddleException $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
            return $results;
            break;
    }
}
```

**result.php:**

```
 <?php if (!is_object($results) || !isset($results->results)): ?>
        <div role="error-info">
            <p><?php echo $results; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <ul class="resultlist listless">
            <?php if($_GET['test'] == 7):
                //test 7 is a single listing
                $result = $results->results;
            ?>
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $result->largeimageurl; ?>"/>
                    <div>
                        <h3><?php echo $result->eventname; ?></h3>
                        <p class="sub">
                            <time datetime="<?php echo $result->date; ?>"><?php echo date('l, jS F Y', strtotime($result->date)); ?></time>
                            | <?php echo $result->venue->name; ?>, <?php echo $result->venue->town; ?>  </p>
                        <p><?php echo $result->description; ?></p>
                        <p><a href="<?php echo $result->link; ?>" target="_blank">Find out more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php foreach ($results->results as $result): ?>
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $result->largeimageurl; ?>"/>
                    <div>
                        <h3><?php echo $result->eventname; ?></h3>
                        <p class="sub">
                            <time datetime="<?php echo $result->date; ?>"><?php echo date('l, jS F Y', strtotime($result->date)); ?></time>
                            | <?php echo $result->venue->name; ?>, <?php echo $result->venue->town; ?>  </p>
                        <p><?php echo $result->description; ?></p>
                        <p><a href="<?php echo $result->link; ?>" target="_blank">Find out more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**index.php:**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body id="main">
        <?php
        $test = "4"; 
        include('skiddle-php-sdk-master/demo/result.php') 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads it is returning the results of **loadTest.php** via the **result.php** template. I have a test parameter '`case: 4`' inside **loadTest.php** and when I go to `http://localhost:3000/index.php?test=4` it returns the correctly filtered results.

**loadTest.php** contains the main API call and `case: 4`.

**result.php** formats the results.

**index.php** contains the include of **result.php** to display the API call result to the user.

I know I can't append a query string directly to an include, but this line in **index.php** '`$test = "4";`' doesn't pass dynamically as a query string, as is shown in other answers on StackOverflow.

I'm not a PHP developer so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I just need to return the results of the API call with the parameter `?test=4` directly in **index.php** without the query string being appended to the URL, any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Look into [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

In `result.php` you're using `$_GET['test']`. This is set from the query parameters of the HTTP request. An `include` doesn't change `$_GET`, since you're still processing the same HTTP request.

Variables set prior to doing an `include` are available in the included script. In your case, the `$test` is available in `result.php`.

In `result.php` there are 2 options:

1. The `test` query parameter should be used
2. A variable `$test` should be used

To choose between that, add the following code to `result.php` (top of the file)

```
$test ??= $_GET['test'];
```

This code means: set `$test` to `$_GET['test']` if the variable isn't set.

Replace `<?php if($_GET['test'] == 7):` with `<?php if($test == 7):`, so the `$test` variable is used.